# Exporting a Video in Quicktime in OS X Lion Shows only Audio

Tags: audio

I'm trying to export a video in OS X Lion to either 480, 720, or 1080 but it only exports the audio file. After the export, the file is in .mov format but, when I play it, the file shows nothing, only the audio is played. Before I updated to Lion, I could export videos just fine. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the source e.g. file type, etc of the original video that you are trying to convert?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "Audio only" option is not selected in the Export window.

[image: "Audio Only" menu item unselected]